# How do I improve performance of a pixel mapping Mat?

Tags: opencv

I have a custom image projection that I create a pixel mapping with. I store the mapping in a `cv::Mat` so that the location of source pixel is stored at the destination pixel. I used the mapping matrix in this way:

```
// Pseudocode
int ih, iw;
for (ih = 0; ih < mapping.rows; ih++){
    for(iw = 0; iw < mapping.cols; iw){
       Point p = mapping[ih,iw];
       destination[ih,iw] = source[p.Y, p.X];
    }
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this?

Comment: this should help [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) though i think use opencv function to do image projection might be faster

Comment: @Ema Thanks, after searching I haven't found a way to do an equirectangular projection in OpenCv I only saw existing answers with custom code.

Comment: seems like opencv does not have equirectangular projection function , so all we can do is scan the image as the link i posted imo

Comment: create the mapping once, then use cv::remap

Comment: @Miki thanks, but in this case the projection is not the same dimensions.